# Redirect to 404 not found page while any of the paths get unmatched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
 <Routes>
  {!userlog ? (
    <Route path="/" element={<AuthLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/signin" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
      <Route path="/changepassword" element={<ChangePassword />} />
    </Route>
  ) : userlog?.user_type===1?(
  <Route path="/" element={<HomeLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="viewproduct/:id" element={<ViewPage />} />
    <Route path="cartlist" element={<CartList />} />
  </Route>
  ):
  <Route path="/" element={<AdminLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="listproducts" element={<ProductsList />} />
  </Route> 
  } 
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/"} />} />
</Routes>
```

What i want,
**Scenario 1(user not logged in):** if user try to navigate "/cartlist" it's redirect to the login page. If user try navigate something not an part of route path's want to navigate 404 not found page.

**Scenario 2(user logged in):** if user try to navigate "/login" it's redirect to the dashboard page. If user try navigate something not an part of route path's want to navigate 404 not found page.

Now what i get is,
User try to navigate any other routes it's navigate to "/" page.

NOTE: I don't want to put private route for every Route's and Also i want routing path like this only..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You really should consider to use some PrivateRoute, as it will decrease the complexity of your rooting. You can then decide if a route is private or public. Why you don't want this solution?

Comment: Because every single route i want to use the private route component to show the exact component. And also i want routing path like this only. 
Example: User not logged in path="/" show's the  login page
                User logged in path="/" show's the dashboard
How can i achieve this?

Comment: You could have a privateroute component, that takes 2 props: a component to be redirected if logged in, and a component to be redirected if not logged in for instance

Comment: Can you please show me the code how to do like that.. please modify the code i mentioned above in my entire Routes.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse due to this line, it will go to "/":

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/"} />} />
```

With the new react-router v6 you can use this by changing:

```
// 404 route
<Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
```

`NotFoundPage` will be your component to tell users that page is not found.

Also, for these, i think you need to put a forward slash / before pathname

```
<Route path="/viewproduct/:id" element={<ViewPage />} />
<Route path="/cartlist" element={<CartList />} />
<Route path="/listproducts" element={<ProductsList />} />
```

Comment: If i use like this,
User not logged in but their try to navigate "/listproducts" page it show's 404 not found page. But i want it's to navigate "/login" page

Comment: Then use exact param

Comment: Same result.. because i'm hiding the route based on the user logged status.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it always resolves to "/" is because it will choose the first route which matches the given pattern, even if it is a partial match. Since all of your routes begin with "/" eg. "/login" etc it always matches "/".

You can prevent this with the "exact" parameter:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<AuthLayout />}>
```

Comment: Understand my question first please..